# Build unikernel mirage on mac OS X

Tags: ocaml, mirage, unikernel

I would like to build a unikernel image of a mirage app for use with Kubernetes on a VirtualBox on my Mac OS X.

How should I go about building it?

All attempts at make specifically deny the use of Darwin.